# wxPython: How do I find out which widget has the focus?

Tags: python, wxpython, focus, wxwidgets

How do I find out which widget in my `wx.Frame` has the focus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use the Window class's static `FindFocus()` method to return the object that has focus.

api: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#FindFocus

examples: http://nullege.com/codes/search/wx.Window.FindFocus/all/page:2